# Multidimensional array in php to save mysqli output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Here is a piece of my code:

```
if($all_pages)
  foreach ($all_pages as $page) 
  {
    $all_hokms = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM qm_hokm WHERE page_id =   ".$page['page_id']."");
   if($all_hokms)
     foreach ($all_hokms as $hokm) 
     {
      $one_page_ahkams[] = array(
    'hokm_id_inPage' => $hokm['hokm_id_inPage'],
    'type' => $page['type'],
    );
     }
    else
     $one_page_ahkams[] = array();

    $all_pages_data[] = array(
    'page_id' => $page['page_id'],
    'done' => $page['done'],
    'checked' => $page['checked'],
    'ahkams' => array($one_page_ahkams), //Here Is the PROBLEM : (((
    );
}
else
    $all_pages_data[] = array();
echo json_encode($all_pages_data);
```

As you see, I want to send multidimensial array() in a json format (from server to client), but how can correct the insertion of an array in an other, I mean that I need to add `$one_page_ahkams` array in `$all_pages_data` one, any ideas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put that:  `'ahkams' => array($one_page_ahkams)`, but check the content of $one_page_ahkams

Comment: this will send ahkams with the value $one_page_ahkams as string not as array ?Are you sure that's what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$one_page_ahkams = array();

$all_pages_data[] = array(
'page_id' => $page['page_id'],
'done' => $page['done'],
'checked' => $page['checked'],
'ahkams' => array($one_page_ahkams);//this comma (,) causes the problem i guess**
);
```

An other way to do it :

```
$all_pages_data[] = array(
'page_id' => $page['page_id'],
'done' => $page['done'],
'checked' => $page['checked'],
'ahkams' => array(['one_page_ahkams']=>$one_page_ahkams);
);
```

Comment: i spoke about comma(,) that you added in the end of your line,delete it.

Comment: Not yet, this is the error " Undefined variable: one_page_ahkams in"

Comment: $one_page_ahkams = array(); without []